# How to send code to the 3ds Max script listener

Tags: python, python-3.x, 3dsmax

I want to send code to the 3ds max script listener for it to run. I thought it could be done by socket programming, but the threading Python module doesn't work in 3ds max. Therefore, when I try to listen to the message received with "while true" without threading, the program freezes. What should I do?

---

I am developing a plugin for 3ds max. But I want some of the code of the program I developed to be kept secret. In addition, I want to use my program as an exe file. However, it is not possible or not easy to interfere with 3ds max from outside. Even if we can interfere, 3ds max uses its own python library. One of them is "pymxs". But it is not possible to install it with the "pip install pymxs" command. If we want to use this library, we have to run every code from the scripting menu of 3ds max. What I want to do is specify the codes to be run in 3ds max in my own program and send it to the client that I made for 3ds max. In the client, I want to run the `exec(received code)` code. In short, I want to send code for 3ds max to be run by its script listener.

[image]

---

3ds Max does not support threading module in Python. This means I can only run 1 process at a time and in socket programming, I have to constantly listen to the server to see if the message is coming. I do this in the "while true" loop, but when I do this I can't use 3ds max because I'm using that 1 process. This is why 3ds max freezes, but I can't avoid this using threads. I need to run scripts from outside whenever I want in 3ds max.

---

Comment: giving some more information on how 3dsmax works, and what code you used might help you get more (or a) answer(s).

Comment: @Anunay Is this enough or ..?

Comment: Hmm it might be enough, though I have no idea how 3dsmax works, and your specific use case, and what the specific problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

[Answer](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/3ds-max-programming/how-to-send-code-to-the-3ds-max-script-listener/m-p/9763951#M26344) by [Drew Avis](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/1985099) from 3ds max forum:

> You could try the approach from this tutorial, which uses Qt for the
> server and ExecuteMAXScriptScript() to run the script.
>
> https://area.autodesk.com/tutorials/using-qt-in-3ds-max-utility-plug-ins/